# How to initialize top-level constants with other constants?

Tags: rust, rust-obsolete

I'd like to initialize some top-level constants using `float::consts::pi`. For example:

```
import float::consts::pi;

const pi2:float = pi*pi;

fn main() {
    io::println(#fmt("pi^2=%.4f", pi2));
}
```

I get these errors:

```
pi2.rs:3:18: 3:20 error: constant contains unimplemented expression type
pi2.rs:3 const pi2:float = pi*pi;
                           ^~
pi2.rs:3:21: 3:23 error: constant contains unimplemented expression type
pi2.rs:3 const pi2:float = pi*pi;
                             ^~
```

Compilation is successful if I write:

```
const pi2:float = 3.14*3.14;
```

But it is not if I define my own `pi`:

```
const pi:float = 3.141592653589793;
const pi2:float = pi*pi;
```

I'm using rust-0.2.

**Update**. Messages in rust-0.3.1 are friendlier, and confirm that the feature is not implemented yet. Referencing same-crate constants is [now allowed](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues/570):

```
$ rustc pi2.rs
pi2.rs:2:18: 2:20 error: paths in constants may only refer to crate-local constants
pi2.rs:2 const pi2:float = pi*pi;
                           ^~
pi2.rs:2:21: 2:23 error: paths in constants may only refer to crate-local constants
pi2.rs:2 const pi2:float = pi*pi;
                              ^~
error: internal compiler error: unexpected failure
note: the compiler hit an unexpected failure path. this is a bug
note: try running with RUST_LOG=rustc=0,::rt::backtrace to get further details and report the results to github.com/mozilla/rust/issues
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error messages:

```
pi2.rs:3:18: 3:20 error: constant contains unimplemented expression type
pi2.rs:3 const pi2:float = pi*pi;
                           ^~
pi2.rs:3:21: 3:23 error: constant contains unimplemented expression type
pi2.rs:3 const pi2:float = pi*pi;
                             ^~
```

mean that there is currently no implementation for these cases in the Rust 0.2 compiler. Rust is unable to resolve the value of the identifier `pi`.

The required functionality may appear in a future release of Rust.

Answer (score 0):

I can't verify because I can't compile Rust on my machine at the moment, but I think your problem might be that the `pi` constant is defined as type `c_float` rather than type `float`. Try:

```
const pi2: c_float = pi*pi;
```

And see if that has any effect. You might also need an import line like `import libc::c_float;` if the type needs to be imported as well.

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't help. `pi` is not `c_float`.